# Convert LINQ query expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var attr = from a in ClsT.Current.GetValues()  
                   from b in a.SomeMethod()  
                   where typeof(ClsA).SomeOtherMethod(b)  
                   select b;
```

How can I convert it to => notation?

Comment: not getting you ...........................

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by _".(dot) notation"_

Comment: it's linq-to-sql. Do you want to convert it to linq?

Comment: We need to know: What dot-Notation is, what GetValues returnes and what the problem exactly is. By the way typeof(CIsA) returns an object of type "Type" which has no SomeOtherMethod defined.

Comment: "dot notation" is actually used in the MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be

```
ClsT.Current.GetValues().SelectMany(a => a.SomeMethod())
                        .Where(b => typeof(ClsA).SomeOtherMethod(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent code would be:

```
var attr = ClsT.Current.GetValues()
           .SelectMany(a => a.SomeMethod())
           .Where(b => typeof(ClsA).SomeOtherMethod(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
ClsT.Current.GetValues().SomeMethod().Where(b => typeof(ClsA).SomeOtherMethod(b))
```